# error CS0103: The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

Tags: android, xamarin

Using `Xamarin`, when I compile my project I get a bunch of error like the one in the title. All the errors error happen on line like this one:

```
LINE: var buttonLogin = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonLogin);
ERROR: error CS0103: The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context
```

However, this is only getting `thrown` by the `compiler`, the code is not underline for a syntax issue and also i can f12 on `Resource.Id.buttonLogin` and find the generated code for he resource.

The code works and looks fine, but the compiler will not stop throwing the errors.

Comment: Did you try deleting the resource designer file? When you build the next time it will auto-generate your `ResourceDesigner.cs` which you can re-add? Usually works for me.

Comment: Have you check this:  https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2850 ?